# Confused about Javascript object properties/fields

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to learn to apply object-oriented principles to my Javascript programming, however I'm confused about how object "fields" or "methods" work in Javascript.  I understand that properties can be dynamically assigned to Javascript objects (functions), but I don't seem to understand how to apply this in practice.

Consider the following example code snippet:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var foo = function()
{
    this.bar = "abc";
    alert(this.bar);
}

foo.start = function()
{
    alert(foo.bar);
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div align='center'>
<input type="submit" onclick = "foo(); foo.start();">
```

When the submit button is clicked, it displays the message `abc`, followed by `undefined`.

This output is contrary to my understanding and intent here.  My understanding is that the line `this.bar = "abc"` creates a new `bar` property (or field) of the `foo` object, and assigns it the value `"abc"`.  However, when I call another method of `foo`, the `bar` property seems to have disappeared.

So, why is `foo.bar` undefined when I access it in `foo.start`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript functions execute in a context that determines what `this` refers to inside the function. When you create a new `foo` object like this:

```
var f = new foo();
```

...then `this` refers to the new object. However, when the `new` operator is omitted, like this:

```
var f = foo();
```

...then the context is the global `window` object. In that case, this line:

```
this.bar = "abc";
```

...sets the value of a property on `window`, *not* the new object.

Comment: +1, though you should add that in the second case, there *is* no new object.

Comment: The this keyword has nothing to do with context (whatever "context" means anyway). It is set by the call and can reference anything that the call sets it to.

Comment: @RobG - "The this keyword refers to the context object (a.k.a. current object)." https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this

Comment: There is no "current object". There is an object that is referenced by this, which is set according to how the function is called or (in ES 5) by using the bind method.

Comment: @RobG - The word "context" has a generic definition that clearly applies. Will the spec convince you? See section 11.1.1: "The this keyword evaluates to the this value of the execution context."

Comment: An execution context is a concept that is (more or less) the local scope of the code being executed. It has a number of properties, like a variable object, scope chain and this. Anyhow, this is likely OT here so I'm likely to get banned or whatever. Discuss in comp.lang.javascript if you want to go further.

Comment: @RobG - I'll retract my link to the spec, since, again, the word "context" has a generic meaning in the English language that clearly applies.